# Converting a column into pandas.datetime or time series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe that looks like this, but with multiple records:

```
ID      Date
1       {'day': 20, 'year': 2018, 'month':9}
```

I am trying to change everything in the Date column in to pandas timeseries format. I was trying to loop through the data and change each entry by doing the following but am getting an error saying that the formats don't match.

```
for index, rows in iterrows:

    x = row['Date']
    pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(x), format = 'day': %d, 'year': %y, \
     'month': %m, dayfirst = True)
```

When running `df.to_dict()`, this is the output:

```
{'ID': {0: '1'}, 'Date':{0: "{'day': 20, 'year': 2018, 'month': 9}"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Steps**

1. Convert column of dictionaries to list of dictionaries
2. Convert list of dictionaries to DataFrame
3. Pass DataFrame to `pd.to_datetime` - This is the cool part!  `pd.to_datetime` accepts a `DataFrame` if there are appropriately named columns.  So happens, your dictionaries have the right keys that will get parsed as column names in step 2.
4. Assign to `'Date'`

---

```
df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(pd.DataFrame(df.Date.tolist())))

   ID       Date
0   1 2018-09-20
```

Comment: I got this error when I did that:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: run `df.to_dict()` and edit your post with the results.

Comment: This is very interesting! Is there somewhere I can read more about the "appropriately named columns" part of passing a dataframe? Your answer helped me identify why I was getting an error trying to run `to_datetime`  on a df-- my column headers are integers, which I presume are not "appropriately named"--but there's nothing mentioned about it in [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) :(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it with this code:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format="{'day': %d, 'year': %Y, 'month': %m}")
```

There should not have been pd.Series.